# kurento Server Still Send Media stream to disconnect Viewer endpoint when chrome refresh webpage

Tags: javascript, webrtc, kurento, kurento-media-server

In One player to many viewer structure, if on viewer's web socket is closed when refreshing browser , KMS server monitor still have stream sending to the viewer IP.
How could I correct to disconnect viewer endpoint to the Sender player?